# All i need to know that the method reverseString takes in an array of char or a normal String?

Tags: java

Write a recursive method stringReverse that takes a character array containing a string as an argument and prints the string backwards. [Hint: Use String method toCharArray, which takes no arguments, to get a char array containing the characters in the String.]

Comment: In many languages a string is an array of chars. What language you're dealing with?

Comment: Judging from method toCharArray, it's likely C#.

Comment: @Quandary no. Look at the case. It's got to be Java. C# has ToCharArray()

Comment: @mihsathe: You're right, it's lower camel case. That escaped my quick glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :
For returning the reversed string, you would use:

```
public static char[] StringReverse(char[] x , int startindex)
{
    int p = x.length;
    if(startindex < p/2)
    {
        char temp = x[startindex];
        x[startindex] = x[x.length - startindex-1];
        x[x.length - startindex-1] = temp;
        return StringReverse(x , startindex+1);
    }
    else
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

For directly printing it, go for this

```
public static void StringReverse(char[] x , int startindex)
{
    int p = x.length;
    if(startindex < p/2)
    {
        char temp = x[startindex];
        x[startindex] = x[x.length - startindex-1];
        x[x.length - startindex-1] = temp;
        StringReverse(x , startindex+1);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

For example, for following input

```
new String("Hello world").toCharArray()
```

The output will be

```
run:
dlrow olleH
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: THE FUNCTION shall PRINT the (reversed) string, not return the (reversed) string.

Comment: @Quandary Thank you for your pointer. I've edited for alternative solution.

Comment: @mihsathe: Don't know Java very well, but that way, doesn't println add a line-brake after every character ?

Comment: @Quandary Somehow I expected somebody to ask this question (rather purposely wrote println for it to be raised). Understand the structure of the recursive function. in my if part, the part before recursive call is responsible for swapping single character at the index = "startindex". Through recursive calls, this part will get executed till whole string is swapped i.e. upto startindex < p/2. Understand that the else part (println) will hence get executed only ONCE the whole string swap has been calculated. The newline hence is added only after the whole reversed sentence.

Comment: @Quandary This is the beauty of recursive functions which can confuse even a seasoned programmer very much. Hence even I most of the times refrain from using recursive ones.

Comment: I didn't really read it, but I remember thinking "it's strange it's only printing once". Now I know why ;-))

Answer (score 0):

```
        char[] pStringReverse(char[] array, int index)
        {
            char tmp = array[index];
            array[index] = array[array.Length - index - 1];
            array[array.Length - index - 1] = tmp;
            index++;
            if (index >= array.Length / 2)
                return pStringReverse(array, index);
            return array;
        }
        string stringReverse(string str)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                return string.Empty;
            return new string(pStringReverse(str.ToCharArray(), 0));
        }
```

Comment: this is not a recursive method